# How to insert route params inside image URL in React Native / Navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, routeparams

On my app's first screen, I have a touchable image that actually send route params to the second screen, which look like this :

```js
<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => navigation.navigate("EcranDetails",{album_id:1,album_name:"David Bowie",album_date:1967,album_img:"david_bowie"})}>
    <Image style={styles.album} source={require('../../assets/images/albums/david_bowie.jpg')} />
</TouchableHighlight>
```

And on my second screen, I would like to have this (image's url string from params inside the require):

```js
<Image style={styles.album} source={require('../../assets/images/albums/david_bowie.jpg')} />
```

But this code doesn't work and I can't find anything related to params in require :

```js
<Image style={styles.album} source={require('../../assets/images/albums/',{JSON.stringify(album_img)},'.jpg')} />
```

---

Any idea why it doesn't work and how I could fix that? Thanks a lot if you can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found.

I've been told that we can't do dynamic require in React Native so I have to write the whole require into the route param to send, and it the receiver screen, in the image's source I just have to write the param name I've sent.

---

Example :

*Sender screen*

```js
<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => navigation.navigate("EcranDetails",
    {album_id:1,album_name:"David Bowie",album_date:1967,album_img:require("../../assets/images/albums/david_bowie.jpg")})}>
    <Image style={styles.album} source={require('../../assets/images/albums/david_bowie.jpg')} />
</TouchableHighlight>
```

*Receiver screen*

```js
const { album_id, album_name, album_date, album_img } = route.params;
<Image style={styles.album} source={album_img} />
```

---

All works fine now. **HOWEVER**, if for some reason it's bad practice or deprecated in any way, I'd love to know why.